# Axios multipart form data

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

In my backend Node.js code, I'm using Axios TypeScript code to upload a document. But I'm facing an issue while using form data. Can anyone help me here? From [Axios documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios):

```
  // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
  // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'
  // When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following types:
  // - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams
  // - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
  // - Node only: Stream, Buffer
```

When I try to use `FormData` I get this error `ReferenceError: FormData is not defined`. So not sure how to use form data in TypeScript and pass to Axios.

Can't I use form data from Node.js?

Comment: What issue? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I try to use `FormData` I get this error ```ReferenceError: FormData is not defined```. So Im not sure how to use form-data in typescript and pass to AXIOS

Comment: [Edit] the question.

Comment: Perhaps it's [this part in the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#form-data).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are doing right now because you didn't provide any example but I am gonna share a piece of code with you, I hope it helps

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('filename', fileData);
axios.post(url, data);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation, the plan is:

use "npm install form-data" install FormData module.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const axios = require('axios');
// with FormData module, you can use it now
const FormData = require('form-data');
var fd = new FormData();
var filename = "example.txt";
var filepath = "C:\\";
var fullname = path.resolve(filepath, filename);
var file_stream = fs.createReadStream(fullname);
fd.append("other_param", "example");
fd.append("filename", filename);
fd.append("file", file_stream);
var headers = fd.getHeaders();
fd.getLength((err, length) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("get file content length failed.");
        return;
    }
    headers["content-length"] = length;
    let options = axios.create({
        url: 'upload_url',
        method: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        headers: headers
    });
    ajax.request(options).then(response => {
        // success

    }, error => {
        // failed

    })
})
```